# Remove @ symbol out of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following:

```
preg_replace('/\B@[^\B ]+/', '<a href="profile.php">$0</a>');
```

Which checks for any string that starts with `@` and ends with a space and turns it into a link.

Now what I need is to create another preg_replace that would remove the `@` symbol from the string, like `@hello`, so that it would just become `hello`.

I need this so that I can change the link in the first preg_replace to become `<a href="profile.php?user=hello>$0</a>`.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap part of your patern in () to create new variable
In this case you will have your match string without @ under $1 variable

```
preg_replace('/\B@([^\B ]+)/', '<a href="profile.php?profile=$1">$0</a>');
```

[Working example](http://regex101.com/r/lC4bL7)

Comment: Please add some explanatory text as well to highlight your changes and why it works. Code is always very on-topic, but StackOverflow isn't just 'CodeExchange'.

Comment: Thanks adam. @mario I understand it now. The additional brackets allowed him to specific what $0 and $1 do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capturing group `( )` around your pattern you want **captured** to separate the captured match and the whole string. You can then place your captured match `$1` where you desire and use `$0` to access your whole string match.

```
preg_replace('/\B@(\S+)/', '<a href="profile.php?profile=$1">$0</a>', $str);
```

You can use `\S` here instead. I don't recommend using `\B` inside of a negated character class.

Regular expression:

```
\B            the boundary between two word chars (\w) 
              or two non-word chars (\W)
 @            '@'
\S+           non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

See a [`working demo`](https://eval.in/61192)